# Gambler's ruin: Probability heads exceed tails by $X$ or more as $N$ increases.

Tags: gambling

I have a question similar to, but different from, the martingale problem.

Assume you are a gambler willing to bet, say, $10\%$ of whatever amount you start with on a fair coin toss.  Then, if at any time the number of tails (losses) exceeds the number of heads (wins) by $10$, you are out of the game.

It seems intuitive to me that as $N$ increases, the probability approaches $1.0$.

However, I don't know how to calculate the probability for any given $N$, say $10$ or $100$ or $1000$.  If, in addition to a formula, someone also knows how to build a Monte Carlo simulation in Excel, that would be excellent!  Thanks in advance for your insights and expertise.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that after $N$ coin tosses, the number of tails never exceeds the number of heads by 10?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. I was able to build a Monte Carlo simulation in Excel.  Clumsy, but it works. I come up with around 60% to 67% going broke in a fair 50% game such as a coin toss after 2000 throws.I've done some reading online, but I don't really understand the formula for putting in real numbers, such as 10 throws, 100 throws, or 1,000 throws.